# How to stop mod_deflate from logging to my php error log?

Tags: apache-2.2, php, logging, log-files, mod-deflate

I have an environment setup on a system I am not in control of and mod_deflate is entering about 3 lines in the error log for every request. They are only the debug level but for some reason the people in control of the server will not disable that level of reporting and the amount of traffic to my site is enough that it crashes the server from all the log entries.

Is there a way to tell mod_deflate not to write to the log or something else I can do on the site level via htaccess or something?

I am on a fairly basic RHEL LAMP server. Thank you!

Excerpt:

```
[Thu Dec 16 15:00:32 2010] [debug] mod_headers.c(743): headers: ap_headers_output_filter()
[Thu Dec 16 15:00:32 2010] [debug] mod_deflate.c(602): [client IP] Zlib: Compressed 50442 to 9565 : URL /index.php
[Thu Dec 16 15:00:34 2010] [debug] mod_headers.c(743): headers: ap_headers_output_filter()
[Thu Dec 16 15:00:34 2010] [debug] mod_deflate.c(602): [client IP] Zlib: Compressed 1191 to 449 : URL /index.php, referer: http://domain/
[Thu Dec 16 15:00:39 2010] [debug] mod_headers.c(743): headers: ap_headers_output_filter()
[Thu Dec 16 15:00:39 2010] [debug] mod_deflate.c(602): [client IP] Zlib: Compressed 50442 to 9565 : URL /index.php, referer: http://domain/
```

Comment: Can you please post the errors? Remove any confidential information from the logs before posting.

Comment: Added the excerpt above.

Comment: Whoops, looks like it is only 2 lines per request. But still 2 too many.

Comment: I say if they won't fix their server then let it crash.

Comment: I wish I had the choice to let it crash. But I have to fix it, now that very well may be that I have to tell them I can't stop it from my end though. I just want to do my due diligence to resolve it.

Comment: you are not alone:  http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/apache/dev/385411

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end, I ended up talking them into editing the virtual host entries for my sites and adding the:

```
LogLevel crit
```

I could not find any such way to do it other than that, or fixing it for the whole server.

Comment: same issue with ubuntu 12.10.... WTF mod_deflate is spamming debug log . I want to keep debug log...